# Trouble Understanding How to Pass a String in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

Could somebody possibly breakdown the proper way to pass a string to a function, have that function put it into a vector and another function print contents of the vector? I'm sure there are tons of duplicates and I have looked at them all(mostly) and still have not been able to apply any of it to this problem, or at least it seems that way to me.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static vector<string> added_messages;
static void addMessage(string message);
static void displayMessages();

int main()
{
    string message = "Testing 1 2 3";
    addMessage(message);
    //printf("%s\n", message);
    return 0;
}

void addMessage(string s)
{
    added_messages.push_back(s);
    //printf("%s\n", s);
}

void displayMessages()
{
    if (added_messages.size() != 0) {
        for (string i : added_messages)
            printf("%s\n", i);
    }
    added_messages.clear();
}
```

It mostly prints out garbage:`4÷/4⌠/`

I'm fairly new to C++ and coming from Java, I just can't figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: The format `%s` is for `char *`, not for `string`. Use `i.c_str()` to get it as a `char*` - or use a different approach to print it, like `cout << i;`

Comment: The main problem here is you are using printf() and not `std::cout`. Your passing of the string is fine.

Comment: All the way down the line, all good answers! Much clearer and to the the point than the other 100s I have read over the past 2 days. Thanks.

Comment: Also, instead of `for (string i : added_messages)`, let it be `for (string& i : added_messages)` - that avoids the string copy during enumeration.

Comment: The `if (added_messages.size() != 0)` check is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get in the habit of declaring string parameters as const reference.

Instead of this:

```
void addMessage(string s)
{
    ...
}
```

This:

```
void addMessage(const string& s)
{
    ...
}
```

Not only does this avoid making a copy of the string, it also lets you pass `string` instances as well as `string literals` and `char*` variables that point to strings.  That is, the above enables all of the following:

```
addMessage("Foobar");

const char* psz = <some other string>
addMessage(psz);

std::string s = "A string";
addMessage(s);
```

And then to print the string correctly with `printf`, use the `.c_str()` member function to get the pointer address of the contents.

Instead of this:

```
printf("%s\n", s);
```

This:

```
printf("%s\n", s.c_str());
```

And it goes without saying that `cout` is preferred over `printf`:

```
cout << s << endl;
```

Putting it altogether:

```
static vector<string> added_messages;
static void addMessage(const string& message);
static void displayMessages();

int main()
{
    string message = "Testing 1 2 3";
    const char* psz = "Yet, another messsage);

    addMessage(message);
    addMessage("Another Message as a string literal);
    addMessage(psz);

    // sample printf statements
    printf("%s\n", message.c_str());
    printf("%s\n", psz);

    // sample cout statements - notice it can handle both pointers and string instances
    cout << message << endl;
    cout << psz << endl;
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    return 0;
}

void addMessage(const string& s)
{
    added_messages.push_back(s);
    printf("%s\n", s.c_str());
}

void displayMessages()
{
    for (const string& i : added_messages)
    {
        printf("%s\n", i.c_str());
    }

    added_messages.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use printf("%s") on string() object - this is the reason you are having the garbage in the output. "%s" expects C string, ie a pointer to char ended with a zero byte.
If you need to print a string() object, use c_str() method to get a C string representation, ie in your case i.c_str(). C++ is mixing C concepts with C++ concepts, so be aware. Use iostream header and std::cout << i to output your object is a C++ way.

About argument passing. In your example, you are doing it okay, but keep in mind that in your case you are doing it by value, ie a copy of the object is created. More efficient is passing by reference.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you are obviously right. I fixed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < added_messages.size(); i++)
    printf("%s\n",added_messages[i].c_str());
```